# TFRecords QueueRunner Error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to load many csv files into a single TFRecord file then be able to feed that TFRecord to my model. I below is all my code and I have tried to break it down as to what I think I am doing.

**Generate data.. the target variable will be the last column.**

```
for i in range(10):
    filename = './Data/random_csv' + str(i) + '.csv'
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 50))).to_csv(filename)
```

**Functions for making TFRecord File**

```
def _int64_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

def _float_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

def _bytes_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def make_q_list(filepathlist, filetype):
    filepathlist = filepathlist
    filepaths = []
    labels = []
    for path in filepathlist:
        data_files = os.listdir(path)
        for data in data_files:
            if data.endswith(filetype):
                data_file = os.path.join(path, data)
                data_file = data_file
                data_label = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(path))
                filepaths.append(data_file)
                labels.append(data_label)

    return filepaths, labels

def rnn_list_format(df):
    input_data_list = []
    output_data_list = []
    y = df[df.columns[-1]]
    X = df[df.columns[:-1]]
    for i in range(len(df)):
        output_data_list.append(y.loc[i])
        input_data_list.append(X.loc[i].as_matrix())

    return input_data_list, output_data_list

def data_split(df):
    y = df[df.columns[-1]]
    X = df[df.columns[:-1]]
    X, y = X.as_matrix(), y.as_matrix()
    return X, y
```

**The function to load csvs into Pandas. Then take the last column and make it my target variable, y. The Pandas dataframes get converted to numpy arrays and written to the TFRecords file.**

```
def tables_to_TF(queue_list, tf_filename, file_type='csv'):
    #Target variable needs to be the last column of data
    filepath = os.path.join(tf_filename)
    print('Writing', filepath)
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tf_filename)
    for file in tqdm(queue_list):
        if file_type == 'csv':
            data = pd.read_csv(file)
            X, y = data_split(data)
        elif file_type == 'hdf':
            data = pd.read_hdf(file)
            X, y = data_split(data)
        else:
            print(file_type, 'is not supported at this time...')
            break
        rec_count = X.shape[0]
        for index in range(rec_count):
            _X = np.asarray(X[index]).tostring()
            _y = np.asarray(y[index]).tostring()
            example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                'X': _bytes_feature(_X),
                'y': _bytes_feature(_y)}))
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

**The function to read the TFRecords file.**

```
def read_and_decode(filename_queue, datashape=160*160*3):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
            'X': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),  
            'y': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        })

    X = tf.decode_raw(features['X'], tf.float32)
    X.set_shape([datashape])
    X = tf.cast(X, tf.float32)

    y = tf.decode_raw(features['y'], tf.float32)
    y.set_shape([1])
    y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32)

    return X, y
```

**Created the batches in Tensorflow**

```
def inputs(train_dir, file, batch_size, num_epochs, n_classes, one_hot_labels=False, datashape=160*160*3):

    if not num_epochs: num_epochs = None
    filename = os.path.join(train_dir, file)

    with tf.name_scope('input'):
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
            [filename], num_epochs=num_epochs)

        X, y = read_and_decode(filename_queue, datashape)

        if one_hot_labels:
            label = tf.one_hot(label, n_classes, dtype=tf.int32)

        example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [X, y], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=2,
            capacity=2000, enqueue_many=False,
            # Ensures a minimum amount of shuffling of examples.
            min_after_dequeue=1000, name=file)

    return example_batch, label_batch
```

**Make the TFRecord file from the data that was created.**

```
filepathlist = ['./Data']
q, _ = make_q_list(filepathlist, '.csv')            
tffilename = 'Demo_TFR.tfrecords'
tables_to_TF(q, tffilename, file_type='csv')
```

**Attempt to load the TFRecord file into a queueRunner.**

```
X_train_batch, y_train_batch = inputs('./',
                                      'Demo_TFR.tfrecords',
                                      50,
                                      1,
                                      0,
                                      one_hot_labels=False,
                                      datashape=50)
sess = tf.Session()
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(init_op)
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
sess.run([X_train_batch, y_train_batch])
```

**ERROR**

```
    INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError'>, Attempting to use uninitialized value input/input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs
     [[Node: input/input_producer/limit_epochs/CountUpTo = CountUpTo[T=DT_INT64, _class=["loc:@input/input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs"], limit=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input/input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs)]]

Caused by op 'input/input_producer/limit_epochs/CountUpTo', defined at:
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2821, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-13-a00f528d3e80>", line 7, in <module>
    datashape=50)
  File "<ipython-input-11-468d0a66f589>", line 94, in inputs
    [filename], num_epochs=num_epochs)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 230, in string_input_producer
    cancel_op=cancel_op)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 156, in input_producer
    input_tensor = limit_epochs(input_tensor, num_epochs)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 96, in limit_epochs
    counter = epochs.count_up_to(num_epochs)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 652, in count_up_to
    return state_ops.count_up_to(self._variable, limit=limit)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 126, in count_up_to
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("CountUpTo", ref=ref, limit=limit, name=name)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value input/input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs
     [[Node: input/input_producer/limit_epochs/CountUpTo = CountUpTo[T=DT_INT64, _class=["loc:@input/input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs"], limit=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input/input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs)]]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OutOfRangeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1020     try:
-> 1021       return fn(*args)
   1022     except errors.OpError as e:

/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1002                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1003                                  status, run_metadata)
   1004 

/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    468           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 469           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    470   finally:

OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_7_input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 50, current size 0)
     [[Node: input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords/random_shuffle_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords/random_shuffle_queue, input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords/n)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OutOfRangeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-a00f528d3e80> in <module>()
     12 coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
     13 threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
---> 14 sess.run([X_train_batch, y_train_batch])

/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    764     try:
    765       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 766                          run_metadata_ptr)
    767       if run_metadata:
    768         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    962     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    963       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 964                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    965     else:
    966       results = []

/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1012     if handle is None:
   1013       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1014                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1015     else:
   1016       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1032         except KeyError:
   1033           pass
-> 1034       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1035 
   1036   def _extend_graph(self):

OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_7_input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 50, current size 0)
     [[Node: input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords/random_shuffle_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords/random_shuffle_queue, input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords/n)]]

Caused by op 'input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords', defined at:
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2821, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-17-a00f528d3e80>", line 7, in <module>
    datashape=50)
  File "<ipython-input-15-468d0a66f589>", line 105, in inputs
    min_after_dequeue=1000, name=file)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 917, in shuffle_batch
    dequeued = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 458, in dequeue_many
    self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 1099, in _queue_dequeue_many
    timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/mcamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_7_input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 50, current size 0)
     [[Node: input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords/random_shuffle_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords/random_shuffle_queue, input_1/Demo_TFR.tfrecords/n)]]
```

**EDIT:**
The below code is what seems to be the root cause of the problem. I think I am not parsing the TFRecord file properly (duh*). I think maybe I am not reading it in as the correct data type. Almost the exact same code will read pictures into a TFRecord and back out.. Only difference is that I am trying to send float32 values through it all.

```
def read_and_decode(filename_queue, datashape=160*160*3):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
            'X': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),  
            'y': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        })

    X = tf.decode_raw(features['X'], tf.float32)
    X.set_shape([datashape])
    X = tf.cast(X, tf.float32)

    y = tf.decode_raw(features['y'], tf.float32)
    y.set_shape([1])
    y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32)

    return X, y
```

Comment: Doing some more playing with this and it seems that the problem lies with my read_and_decode function... When I try to run it, the program just sits and doesn't do anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you distill the problem down to a small self-contained example? There's too much code here to make it easy to work out the problem.

Comment: The above code is all self-contained..it will execute and provide the above error. 
The below line of code seems to be the main problem, but I don't know what is wrong. My best guess is that I am reading the TFRecord file as the wrong datatype but I don't know
`X, y = read_and_decode(filename_queue, datashape)`

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to follow there so I'm not sure, but the quickest thing to check is whether your "num_epochs" is set properly. Those OutOfRangeErrors are thrown when the epoch limit has been reached.